# list items in horizontal line on browser resize

Tags: html, css, resize, viewport

I have a list items which has default width in percentage and min-width in pixel. I need to avoid percentage div to resize when the browser viewport reach the some extent of with.

First two li are working fine but the third li is going to next line when you resize the browser. I need to make tat also in the same line.

Here is my code

```
.project-data-panel{
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom:10px;
  width:100%;
  min-width:758px
}


.project-detail-subheadleft{
    width:98%;
    min-width:330px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#F7F7F7;
    border-bottom:solid #ccc 1px;
    padding:5px
}
.project-detail-subheadleft ul{
    float:right 
}
.project-detail-subheadleft li{ 
    display:inline-block;   
    padding-left:2px;
}
.gma-head{
    display:inline-block;
    width:55%;
    font-size:12px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    min-width: 180px;
}
.project-detail-subheadright{
    width:48%;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#fff;

}
.pmr-head{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 195px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-bottom: solid #ccc 1px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    position:relative
}

.activity-head{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-bottom: solid #ccc 1px;
}

.project-detail-header li, .project-data > ul > li{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:left

}
li.project-detail-headerleft, .project-data-headerleft{
    width:44%   
}
li.project-detail-headermiddle{

}
li.project-detail-headerright{
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 11px;
}
.project-data-headerright{
    width:31%   
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/uCAhIbi/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `min-width` from all elements and adjust some width in % also.

[fiddle demo](http://jsbin.com/uCAhIbi/4/)

Comment: But y '6.13.9August' text is going to next line?

Comment: And I need min-width in px for middle div

Comment: @Sowmya Please check my update. Also let me know what thing you still need in my fiddle demo.

Comment: Yeah. For some reasons I want that middle div to be fixed width

Comment: @Sowmya But if you give fixed width then when you see it in small window then it will automatically move to next line.

Comment: Correct that is what I want to solve now. I Need browser to create browser horizontal scroll in that case